# Apps crash when tryin to go online, /data/data/hotplug/cmd is missing

Tags: root-access, internet

All of the sudden, some of my apps (not all of them) have started crashing and crashing the entire OS when trying to go online. The logcat shows:
E (675) could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd' file is missing

This happens with facebook messenger, Gett, facebook itself ( who doesnt crash but cant go online), and more. Browser, whatsapp and others arent affected.

Another issue started at approximatly the same time, where my wifi switch widget refuses to go offline. Turning wifi off through the settings shows to be ok, but the outside widgets stays on, and suddenly finds new networks and the wifi goes live again by itself.

Any ideas or other information I can provide?

Cheers

BTW a rooted thl 4000, but there was a long time since I rooted.

Comment: If this second issue is unrelated, you should probably ask a new question. If you think it's related then please specify this in the question.

Comment: As I stated, i don't really know if it's related but it started at the same time, so it probably is :)

Answer (score 0):

In respect to your first question try changing your CPU governor with [No-frills CPU Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.sineo.android.noFrillsCPU) app.
Change it to performance for higher performance. Just be careful as you could cause harm to your phone if you play around too much.

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt seem to fix the problem. It appears more and more like a link2sd internet-related problem.